# Перенос данных из одного input в другой

Tags: javascript

Есть две формы, нужно что бы человек вводил номер телефона в input от одной формы и они дублировались в input другой.
И при выборе любого из 3 мессенджеров так же нажималась кнопка "Зарегистрироваться бесплатно"

Находил обычные скрипты переноса значений, но почему то они не срабатывают

https://nl-education.com/test-form

http://joxi.ru/DrleqOOT0lRxjm

Comment: Покажите свой код, сложно без кода понять вашу проблему

Comment: это 2 формы которые генерируются разными платформами вот сюда их обе поместил https://nl-education.com/test-form

Comment: так а код скрипта копирующий можно?

Comment: <script>
     $("input-phone").keyup(function () {
     var value = $(this).val();
     $("#phone").val(value);
   });
</script>

Comment: это код для копирования значений, для нажатий еще не сделал, но для начала перенос значений хотелось бы реализовать

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".copy").click(function()
{
$("#copy").val($("#tel").val());

console.log($("#tel").val());
 });
```

это код js(jquery)

```
<input type="text" name="tel" id="tel">
<input type="text" name="copy" id="copy">
<div class="copy">send</div>
```

это html

Comment: увы не подошло(

Comment: вам нужно чтобы данные переносились по нажатию кнопки?

Comment: да, что бы при нажатии на любой из мессенджеров (фб, вайбер, телеграмм) переносились данные из поля номера телефона верхней формы в нижнюю и так же нажималась кнопка "зарегистрироваться бесплатно"

Comment: при нажатии на мессенджер сделайте переход на ссылку регистрации, в чем проблема тогда? Теперь другой вопрос, почему у вас не работает мой код, покажите свой, потому что у меня все работает

Comment: проблема в том, что при выборе мессенджера происходит редирект в мессенджер

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".copy").click(function()
{
$("#copy").val($("#tel").val());

console.log($("#tel").val());

$("button").trigger("click");
});
$("button").click(function()
{
  alert("Click button");
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]